# Нужно вывести данные из базы данных в Listview/

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursoradaper

При создании активити создается база данных, наполняется данными, если она пуста. Затем нужно вывести данные из нее в listview. В итоге приложение вылетает при запуске. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etFindNote;
    ListView list;
    Button btnAdd, btnMenu;
    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    Cursor c;

    final String ATTRIBUTE_DATE = "date";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NOTE = "note";

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etFindNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFindNote);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
                cv.put("date", "07.05.2017");
                cv.put("note", "Hello");
                db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
            }
        }
        c.close();
        c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        String[] from = new String[]{"date", "note"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.itemDate, R.id.itemNote};
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, c, from, 


to,0);
        list.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(list);

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper (Context context) {
        //конструктор
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    //создание таблицы с полями
    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
        + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + "date text,"
        + "note text"+");");
    }
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    }
    }
    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.alex.notes.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFindNote"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Поиск заметки"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="425dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Создать"
            android:onClick="NewNoteClick"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Меню"
            android:onClick="MenuClick"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemDate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы закрываете Cursor, а потом еще делаете с ним запрос

```
c.close();
c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

метод [close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close()) закрывает курсор, освобождая все его ресурсы и делает его полностью недействительным. Создавайте новый `Cursor`.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, но все равно вылетает при запуске приложения.

Comment: @AlexAlex приложите в вопрос ошибку какую пишет.

Comment: Судя по логам, не работает передача курсора адаптеру

Comment: Попробуйте вместо getWritableDatabase() использовать getReadableDatabase(), из за него могут появляться ошибки, связанные с полномочиями

Comment: И добавьте сюда лог ошибки